# A Theory of Almost Everything?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, spacetime, dark-matter

Before I present this theory, I ask that you take the time to read this disclaimer.

*I do not claim to have an excellent knowledge of physics, it is actually rather limited. Therefore, I am not claiming this theory to be completely accurate or without flaws. Honestly, I expect it to be completely wrong. I apologize in advance if I say things that seem to completely contradict basic known physical truths. But I hope that I can find some constructive criticism within this post to grow from. I also do not know if some of these ideas are completely mine, or if they have been mentioned by someone else in the past. Also, I have only researched very little about dark matter, all I know is it pertains to some form of mysterious gravity, so my knowledge of dark matter is also very limited (but whose isn't). Lastly, I will try my best to explain this to where it can be understood, but it may be difficult without visual aids. And no, I do not have any mathematics to back this up. I do not yet have enough confidence in the theory to spend the time learning and developing them.*

But without further a due, here is my theory of what lead to the big bang, the formation of our universe, and a possible explanation for dark matter.

Einstein theorized that gravity is due to a depression in space-time by an object. The denser the body, the larger the gravity well. Therefore, a black hole's seemingly infinite density, creates a very large gravity well trapping anything in that comes close enough. But I'm sure you already knew this. However, I have heard a lot of theories that a black hole's density is infinite, and maybe it is for all we know. But I think it's not the durability of the black hole that matters, it’s the very fabric of space and time. I theorize that maybe space-time has a ripping point. That there is a point at which a black hole becomes so extremely dense that it cannot be held together any longer by space-time. But then where would all the contents go? Well I don't believe it can be sent a burst back into the current universe in which the black hole originally existed. It enters into a new void in space, possibly leaving a wormhole behind, a sort of space-time scar from the event. And in this new void, is where the bang happens. The mass contained within is finally no longer held together by space-time. It explodes into a new "universe", and that is the big bang. However, not everything can escape the gravity well of the core contents. The core of the mass, making up most of it, instantly collapses back into another super massive black hole, I will get to the relevance of this later. The outer remnants of the mass are scattered out into the void. But within this, exists other black holes floating about. And the matter that did not get trapped into the any black holes, begins to orbit them, due to their strong depressions in space-time. This causes the formation of galaxies.

And now for the super massive black hole and dark matter. There is a strange gravity that exists that seems to be originating from invisible mass. This "invisible mass" has been labeled Dark Matter. But is it possible that it is only the unseen effects of the gravity from this super massive black hole at the origin point of the big bang? I'm talking about a black hole larger than anything imaginable. It may be possible that we are all just sliding up the "bowl" of this black hole, still accelerating from the energy released from the big bang. But surely we can't accelerate forever. Well all this time, the black hole has been slowly consuming the innards of the universe, growing in density.  And finally the effects of its gravity is strong enough to counteract our acceleration. Maybe we will start receding back down this gravity well, like a quarter on coin funnel. But then this would mean we would be living in an oscillating universe. Where we would bang into existence and then slowly shrink back and do it all over again. So that would mean where is the universe we were originally born from when it ripped through space and time. Well that is the largest flaw, that I know of, I am having trouble figuring out. But again, I'm not a physicist of any sort, so I do not completely understand the universe and dark matter theory. This was just a shot in the dark, no pun intended.

And there it is, my theory of everything. I hope I haven't embarrassed myself too much, haha. I couldn't think of anywhere else to share this but here, so I hope you all at least enjoy the thought.

Comment: It is tiresome to read such a long explanation. Can't you make it more concise? It would be a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please read [this post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4538/58382) about asking non mainstream physics questions. Also note that this site is all about *questions*, and for how is corrently stated your post contains none. Finally, I would mention that physics is all about quantitative prediction of experiments throught equations relating quantities. What kind of new predictions would your "theory" provide?

Comment: My question is, what does not make sense with this theory? I am asking for a critique on why this theory wouldn't work. That way I, and possibly others, may learn something from it. I'm sorry if this was not an appropriate forum to post it on. I wasn't sure where else to.

Comment: If you just make stuff up (about the politest term I can think of for what you wrote),  unless you're forming a new religion, expect to be soundly rejected by everyone.

Comment: I do not think your ideas amount to a theory, at least as currently understood. For today's standard, any vague  ideas must be backed up by mathematical foundations and predictive power. Your theory has the vague ideas but lack the last component.

Comment: "I do not claim to have an excellent knowledge of physics, it is actually rather limited.", yet you do claim to have a Theory of Almost Everything. It's so convenient that Almost Everything fits within the compass of your limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your idea does make on important prediction, which is that the universe originated at a point in space (the location of a black hole) and we should be sucked towards that point, eventually being sucked in and the cycle happening all over again.

There is plenty of observational evidence that your theory can not be correct. Firstly, the universe did not start at a 'point' in space-time. You can think of spacetime as being *created* by the big bang, meaking the idea of a 'point' in space meaningless (see second point).

Secondly (and hopefully this will make the first point more intuitive) the universe is not shrinking towards a point in space, but *expanding* in all directions. You mentioned that we are accelerating and that we may eventually be pulled back to the point of origin of the universe once gravity takes hold, however this shows a slight misunderstanding of how we are accelerating. You can think of this mysterious expansion (its currently not at all well understood) as creating spacetime in the universe. The classic example is to think of the universe as the surface of a balloon being blown up - if you were to imagine a two dots on the balloon, separated by some distance, the distance between the dots would increase as the balloon was blown up, but the dots themselves would not be 'traveling' on the balloon, rather there would be space created between them.

Thirdly, I don't think your understanding of Dark Matter is correct. The main evidence for Dark matter is that galaxies we observe are moving in such as way that disagrees with the predictions of general relativity. Those predictions would be correct provided that there was some matter in said galaxies that we could not see - Dark Matter. It is also fairly well accepted that each galaxy probably has a super-massive black hole in its center.